# Missing module attribute showing up for a linked Python script

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

In my learning to use Python one of the things I am trying to do is to separate like functions/details in to different scripts. In a previous script that I wrote that was a batch file renamer, I have created a GUI and I wanted to separate the GUI and its specific functions into a dedicated script that the parent script can call upon at initial opening.

The parent script is called TVShowRenamerv2.py
The GUI script is called GUI.py

From the parent script, this is imported

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog, filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import GUI as g
```

And then called on a line near the end of the script

`rg = g.Renamer_GUI()`

I am using VS Code as my IDE, and I get no errors prior to running the script. Once I do run the script, I get the following error:

```
  File "TVShowRenamerv2.py", line 4, in <module>
    import GUI as g
  File "D:\Projects\Python\TVShowRenamer\v2\GUI.py", line 3, in <module>
    import TVShowRenamerv2 as t2
  File "D:\Projects\Python\TVShowRenamer\v2\TVShowRenamerv2.py", line 172, in <module>
    rg = g.Renamer_GUI()
AttributeError: module 'GUI' has no attribute 'Renamer_GUI'
```

This is from the GUI.py

```
from tkinter import ttk
import TVShowRenamerv2 as t2

class Renamer_GUI():
```

VS Code seems to tie the two together properly because I don't get any errors when I call functions from the two scripts, so I am not sure what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you running the script? You might actually be importing a different GUI.py file than you are expecting (put `print(g.__file__)` after the import to confirm). Secondly, you have circular imports (eg X imports Y and Y imports X) leading me to guess that you are actually importing a different module than you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was implementing a circular import of the two different scripts (ie, both scripts were importing each other). As a more experienced Python dev friend pointed out to me, this is bad.

We initially solved the problem by placing the items that the debugger was stating as missed attributes in one of the scripts inside a **name** == **main** if statement, but that was a short term fix that ultimately ended up creating additional issues.

So I ended up creating a third script (A controller, a GUI, and now a manipulable values). The controller would create the TK window and instantiate the GUI class inside it, and then the GUI could manipulate the values in the third script. This seemed to be the better long term solution.

Thank you very much for the assistance!